# Labels alignment in UIStackView

Tags: ios, uilabel, uistackview

I have `UIStackView` with 2 `UILabel`s.

```
# [LeftLabel: can be very long, lines = 0][RightLabel: text = NEW, width >= 30]
```

In most cases `RightLabel` can be hidden, so I chose `UIStackView` to automatically make `LeftLabel` fit width of `UIStackView`, if `RightLabel` is hidden.

So if `RightLabel` is visible, I need to position them depending on `LeftLabel` text.

## I want this

If `LeftLabel.text = "Short"`:

```
# [LeftLabel: Short][RightLabel: NEW (take rest of the space)]
```

Else if `LeftLabel.text = "Very very long description"`

```
# [LeftLabel: Very very       ][RightLabel: NEW         ]
# [           long description][(take rest of the space)]
```

## But I get

If `UIStackView` distribution = `fill`

```
# [LeftLabel][RightLabel] # Both take 1/2 of `UIStackView` width
```

If `UIStackView` distribution = `fillProportionally`

```
# [       LeftLabel         ][RightLabel]
# RightLabel.width becomes 30, and LeftLabel takes the rest
```

I've tried to make `leftLabel.sizeToFit()` and so on, tried to play with hugging and compression of both labels, but it doesn't help. I'm not sure, if all this make sense in `UIStackView`.

Is it possible to get this behavior with `UIStackView` or I need to use `UIView` and position labels with constraints?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried all the distribution types?

Comment: I think it's better to create a usual UIView and use constraints for labels.